# Storing color array for each user in database

Tags: database-design

I am considering the problem of user-configurable color schemes for a website.  The site currently has a collection of flat CSS files, which are selectable by users (selection is stored as a column in the user table of a SQL database).  This has led to a maintenance problem, in that updating the files to extend the site's CSS is not feasible.

In particular, there is a collection of css selectors that I would like users to be able to choose color values for.  That is, in pseudo-code,

```
body {
    background-color : <% print user_bg_color %>;
}
```

My question is not concerned with the mechanics of implementing such CSS generation.  Rather,

> Is there a standard practice or best way for storing such a collection of values?

[EDIT]

> If there is no standard way, what are some techniques?

[/EDIT]

Any such technique should be extendable, in the sense that further modification of the site's CSS would allow for the addition of new variables by the site admins.  Currently, there are about 30 color schemes consisting of 90 variables each, and about 35,000 users.

Comment: I don't think there is a best practice on this other than make it readable and scalable without over complicating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is necessarily a standard way, but what seems obvious and simple to me is a essentially many-to-many table (although your css variable names aren't necessarily stored in the database independently, unless you need to add more data than the variable name) with:

- user_id
- css_variable_name_or_id (id if it refers to a sql table of css values)
- value

This way you can easily select all the css for a user, or independently the user_id and css_variable_name for a user.

Put an index on user_id, at least.  That should make performance decently fast. (You may don't want one on css_variable_name because of all the duplicates, but it would be worth testing both ways)